# Webpack Babel generate wrong JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I am getting `banners is not defined` from the following code.

```
export const selectInfoBanners = createSelector(
  selectInfo,
  info => {
    const banners = [...info.banners];
    while (banners.length < 2) {
      banners.push({ url: "" });
    }
    return banners;
  }
);
```

But the code generated is

```
var selectInfoBanners = Object(reselect__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["createSelector"])(selectInfo, function(a) {
    for (var b = _toConsumableArray(a.banners); 2 > b.length; )
        b.push({
            url: ""
        });
    return banners // <-- Why is it not b?
});
```

I am using `@babel/core@7.2.2`, `babel-loader@8.0.5`.

Comment: yes, looks like a bug. better fire this into their github(and include babel's plugins applied - it may be their fault)

Comment: @skyboyer I will do that when I have time to create a minimal reproducible repository.